# Does the infinite series converge with n^k in the numerator and the polynomial n^(k+1) + n^k + n^(k-1) + ... 1 as k goes to infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, infinity

I know that I am asking this question the wrong way, but hopefully one of you understands what I am getting at. Does it converge?
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty } \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{n^{k+1}+n^{k}+... +n +1}
$$

Comment: That simply makes no sense. The series diverges for every $k\in \Bbb N$. There is no sequence to compute its limit.

Answer (score 2):

No. To see it, use equivalents:
$$n^{k+1}+n^k\dots+n+1=\frac{n^{k+2}-1}{n-1}\sim_\infty\frac{n^{k+2}}{n}=n^{k+1},$$
hence $\;u_n\sim_\infty\dfrac{n^k}{n^{k+1}}=\dfrac 1n$.